problem in android re-establish connection after USBOutTransferResult's status show OK
first, i am new to webusb and usb programming. i just want to make this thing (https://medium.com/@denyskarpov/send-android-application-data-directly-to-browser-with-android-accessory-mode-webusb-4a459e173a13) happen. The result is negative so i am here to ask further.
please check picture below, after USBOutTransferResult's status show OK, then android unexpectedly trigger usb disconnection, so i was unable to send new message. btw, i dun create android app to read stream due to my android programming is lame, will this is root cause of case?

i expect even without android app to read the usb stream, the usbDevice.transferOut will still be working and android wont disconnect the connection accordingly.
